# Cannot replicate POST request with JSON body

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to replicate a POST request to a site and I'm sure I'm passing the right form arguments but somehow the site isn't responding what it should.

Copying the `curl` request from Chrome gives (it is modified):

```
curl 'https://example.com/somepath' -H 'origin: https://example.com/' -H 'x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest' -H 'pragma: no-cache' -H 'user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.110 Safari/537.36' -H 'content-type: application/json'--data '{"foor":"var"}' --compressed
```

Here is my Scrapy request:

```
FormRequest(url="https://example.com/somepath", formdata={'foo': 'var'})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing to include the `Content-Type` header, and also you won't be able to do that request with `FormRequest`. Just use normal `Request` with the correct body:

```
import json

...

Request(
    url="https://example.com/somepath", 
    body=json.dumps({'foo': 'var'}), 
    headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
)
```